# DDD - How should the domain rules be designed so the upper layers know when a rule was broken?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, cqrs, business-rules

Example : ShoppingCart entity has a rule that no more than 10 items can be added . The shoppingCart will have a method addItemToCart(item) that will check if it the limit was not exceeded. If the cart limit is exceeded the cart should somehow inform somehow the upper layer calling that method that a specific business rule was broken.

One thing that comes in mind is to use exceptions but these seem an unproper use of exceptions. How should the messaging be done? What patterns could help for this problem , keeping the domain unrelated to the other layers and properly encapsulated ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the rule is max 10 items in the cart, then `ShoppingCart` should expose `isFull()` so upper layers can check before calling `addItem()`. Or disable `Add` button, or whatever - `ShoppingCart` doesn't know how the rule information is used and shouldn't assume it will only be required when `addItem` is called. As a safety check `addItem` can throw an exception but this shouldn't be the primary mechanism to communicate to upper layer.

Comment: I like this way of thinking,exposing everything about the domain. I guess i was trying to encapsulate some of the logic in the domain , but this might lead to improper behaviour of the upper layers . I was just thinking if I should really be on the side of never letting a domain object be in an invalid state by doing the checks on it's own. I guess the best option and the proper one is to write the rules on the domain side but expose them to the upper layers and let them do the checking.Also the"disable add button"is very good way to stop the domain object dosomething after the check failed +1

Comment: Thanks! it led me on the right track ! It's basically like leting the upper layers request and run the checks and the domain layer will cache the checks result and use them when needed .

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a recipe for that, it really depends on your app. For your specific example I believe things are quite simple: ShoppingCart is pretty much a container and even that it's a domain concept it's still a container. Also the UI should be aware of this rule too, so it shouldn't allow for a greater number of items than it suppose to accept.

But let's say the shopping cart POST model get to the controller. It's easy to have a service or use directly the ShopppingCart object to validate the input. The point is, you expect this kind of situation so you deal with it as fast as possible. but if you decide that the UI shouldn't allow this to happen in the first place, then the ShoppingCart should throw an exception, because it's a bug (UI permitted an invalid operation).

Personally, I wouldn't have a ShoppingCart domain concept modeled. The ShoppingCart would be an input model used to create an Order from it.

As a thumb rule, if I expect some situations (which require to give feedback to the user) then I'd have some validation before I'm using the data to update the domain. The domain objects should throw everytime a business rule is violated. Once again, there isn't a recipe, I'd probably do different things in different apps.

Comment: Well, if you don't put the business rules inside the domain you're gonna end up having an anemic domain model and you should just skip that layer and use only controllers/services/comands/commandHandlers. So knowing that a domain layer is really there, it will process some business rules that might break. The UI is just should handle basic checks , business rules (most of them at least) should be in the domain . So when the rules are broken (my example was a simple one , you took it too seriously) the upper layers need to know abi=out it (service/ui etc) .

Comment: "but if you decide that the UI shouldn't allow this to happen in the first place, then the ShoppingCart should throw an exception, because it's a bug" . The domain should not care about the other layers , it only needs to know what's happening in it's own layer . Where the data is coming from and if it came through some filters is not the domain concern. The domain is the core (is not a paralel layer , is the core layer and knows nothing about the upper layers that's why is called "domain driven")

Comment: well thank you for the DDD tutorial, however you missed the "there isn't a recipe" part so I can give you my thoughts only about some concrete scenario. The domain doesn't care about other layers that's why I've said it should throw. But the app consists of more than the domain and there's nothing preventing the UI to _use_ a domain validator (which can be implemented as a service, or static method etc). The business rule is still part of the Domain, but it's re used outside it. I think you're trying to come up with a complete "works for every app" approach, but it simply isn't one.

Comment: I can only give guidelines, principle or suggestions about specific scenarios. Nobody can tell you the best way of doing everything in any app.

Answer (score 0):

The same way as in any other program: choose a method that works well with your team and with your implementation environment. Exceptions work fine.